# Number of months between two dates

Tags: r, date

Is there a standard/common method/formula to calculate the number of months between two dates in R?

I am looking for something that is similar to [MathWorks months function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/finance/months.html)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19687995/59087

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I was about to say that's simple, but `difftime()` stops at weeks. How odd.

So one possible answer would be to hack something up:

```
# turn a date into a 'monthnumber' relative to an origin
R> monnb <- function(d) { lt <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(d, origin="1900-01-01")); \
                          lt$year*12 + lt$mon } 
# compute a month difference as a difference between two monnb's
R> mondf <- function(d1, d2) { monnb(d2) - monnb(d1) }
# take it for a spin
R> mondf(as.Date("2008-01-01"), Sys.Date())
[1] 24
R>
```

Seems about right.  One could wrap this into some simple class structure. Or leave it as a hack :)

*Edit:* Also seems to work with your examples from the Mathworks:

```
R> mondf("2000-05-31", "2000-06-30")
[1] 1
R> mondf(c("2002-03-31", "2002-04-30", "2002-05-31"), "2002-06-30")
[1] 3 2 1
R>
```

Adding the `EndOfMonth` flag is left as an exercise to the reader :)

*Edit 2:* Maybe `difftime` leaves it out as there is no reliable way to express fractional difference which would be consistent with the `difftime` behavior for other units.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. 
That's a clever trick. 

Speaking of units, I found out that this also works..

>as.numeric(as.Date('2009-10-1') - as.Date('2009-8-01'), units = 'weeks')
> as.numeric(as.Date('2009-10-1') - as.Date('2009-8-01'), units = 'days')

but it stops at 'weeks' as well.

Comment: I think that is just clever overloading of the - operator to invoke the same `difftime()` function. "No Free Lunch" as the saying goes :)

Comment: I found this very slow for large datasets. The answer by Manoel Galdino below is much faster.

Comment: @anotherfred And potentially false. Quick example are dates 2017-01-31 and 2018-03-01. Gives '13' here with his first answer (once we add the missing `as.numeric()`, and '12' with the second answer.  My answer gives '14' as one would want.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel sorry, should have clarified - I meant his first method is useful for cases like mine where I have a large dataset but all dates are the 1st of the month.

Answer (score 68):

I think this is a closer answer to the question asked in terms of parity with MathWorks function

**MathWorks months function**

```
MyMonths = months(StartDate, EndDate, EndMonthFlag)
```

My R code

```
library(lubridate)
interval(mdy(10012015), today()) %/% months(1)
```

Output (as when the code was run in April 2016)

```
[1] 6
```

**Lubridate [package]** provides tools that make it easier to parse and manipulate dates. These tools are grouped below by common purpose. More information about each function can be found in its help documentation.

**interval {lubridate}** creates an Interval-class object with the specified start and end dates. If the start date occurs before the end date, the interval will be positive. Otherwise, it will be negative

**today {lubridate}** The current date

**months** **{Base}** Extract the month These are generic functions: the methods for the internal date-time classes are documented here.

**%/% {base}** indicates integer division AKA ( x %/% y ) (up to rounding error)

Comment: This worked for me while some of the others did not.

Comment: This also worked for me while others did not.  I had to compare my results with the datediff function in SPSS.  This matched those results.

Answer (score 58):

A simple function...

```
elapsed_months <- function(end_date, start_date) {
    ed <- as.POSIXlt(end_date)
    sd <- as.POSIXlt(start_date)
    12 * (ed$year - sd$year) + (ed$mon - sd$mon)
}
```

Example...

```
>Sys.time()
[1] "2014-10-29 15:45:44 CDT"
>elapsed_months(Sys.time(), as.Date("2012-07-15"))
[1] 27
>elapsed_months("2002-06-30", c("2002-03-31", "2002-04-30", "2002-05-31"))
[1] 3 2 1
```

To me it makes sense to think about this problem as simply subtracting two dates, and since [`minuend − subtrahend = difference` (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction), I put the later date first in the parameter list.

Note that it works fine for dates preceeding 1900 despite those dates having internal representations of year as negative, thanks to the rules for subtracting negative numbers...

```
> elapsed_months("1791-01-10", "1776-07-01")
[1] 174
```

Answer (score 50):

There may be a simpler way. It's not a function but it is only one line.

```
length(seq(from=date1, to=date2, by='month')) - 1
```

e.g.

```
> length(seq(from=Sys.Date(), to=as.Date("2020-12-31"), by='month')) - 1
```

Produces:

```
[1] 69
```

This calculates the number of whole months between the two dates. Remove the -1 if you want to include the current month/ remainder that isn't a whole month.

Comment: This doesn't always give expected results.

`length(seq(from=as.Date("2015-01-31"), to=as.Date("2015-03-31"), by='month')) = 3`
Also, 
`length(seq(from=as.Date("2015-01-31"), to=as.Date("2015-04-30"), by='month'))  = 3`

Comment: The code above now returns an error because Sys.Date()>"2020-12-31"  by now. It still works if you change 'from' and 'to' arguments.

Comment: Since `seq` dispatches `seq.Date` in this case, directly using `seq.Date` is faster.

Answer (score 17):

There is a message just like yours in the R-Help mailing list (previously I mentioned a CRAN list).

Here [the link](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/11/7326.html). There are two suggested solutions:

- There are an average of 365.25/12 days per month so the following expression gives the number of months between d1 and d2:

> ```
> #test data 
> d1 <- as.Date("01 March 1950", "%d %B %Y")    
> d2 <- as.Date(c("01 April 1955", "01 July 1980"), "%d %B %Y")
> # calculation 
> round((d2 - d1)/(365.25/12))
> ```

- Another possibility is to get the length of `seq.Dates` like this:

> ```
> as.Date.numeric <- function(x) structure(floor(x+.001), class = "Date")
> sapply(d2, function(d2) length(seq(d1, as.Date(d2), by = "month")))-1
> ```

Comment: Assumes that all dates have a whole number of  months between them, but useful.

Comment: I tried out your first example, but the output indicates "Time difference in days" rather than "Time difference in months."

Answer (score 6):

```
library(lubridate)
```

case1: naive function

```
mos<-function (begin, end) {
      mos1<-as.period(interval(ymd(begin),ymd(end)))
      mos<-mos1@year*12+mos1@month
      mos
}
```

case2: if you need to consider only 'Month' regardless of 'Day'

```
mob<-function (begin, end) {
      begin<-paste(substr(begin,1,6),"01",sep="")
      end<-paste(substr(end,1,6),"01",sep="")
      mob1<-as.period(interval(ymd(begin),ymd(end)))
      mob<-mob1@year*12+mob1@month
      mob
}
```

Example :

```
mos(20150101,20150228) # 1
mos(20150131,20150228) # 0
# you can use "20150101" instead of 20150101

mob(20150131,20150228) # 1
mob(20150131,20150228) # 1
# you can use a format of "20150101", 20150101, 201501
```

Comment: interval(mdy(20150101), mdy(20150228)) %/% months(1)

Just use the lubridate's native function interval.

Comment: thank you mtelesha.  
However, in my business, I need to calculate 'month count' of 2 days often.    
For example, months between 20150131 and 20150201 have to be 1.    
So, I used to make 'mob' user defined function.    
Do you know how to make this using lubridate?

Comment: I think you would can either use month(ymd) - month(ymd).  Or you could make three columns one for year, month and day.

Comment: Sure, but in case of different year, it will not work.
For example, month(ymd(20170101)) - month(ymd(20161231)) = -11 not 1

Answer (score 6):

For me this is what worked:

```
library(lubridate)

Pagos$Datediff <- (interval((Pagos$Inicio_FechaAlta), (Pagos$Inicio_CobFecha)) %/% months(1))
```

The output is the number of months between two dates and stored in a column of the Pagos data frame.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but this doesn't' give any decimal places. Any advice?

Comment: I am afraid this only gives you the number of months. but not with commas. My opinion is that instead of that, should calculate in term of days. I might be more precise for your case.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(lubridate)
date1 = "1 April 1977"
date2 = "7 July 2017"

date1 = dmy(date1)
date2 = dmy(date2)
number_of_months = (year(date1) - year(date2)) * 12 + month(date1) - month(date2)
```

> **Difference in months = 12 * difference in years + difference in months.**
>
> Following may need to be corrected using `ifelse` condition
>   for the month subtractions

Comment: maybe worth to note that this results in negative numbers - so either changing date1/date2 or use `abs(etc)`  . I think this is a very easy and straight forward solution for getting a `guestimate` of months

Answer (score 3):

You can use as.yearmon() function from zoo package. This function converts a Date type variable to a year-month type variable. You can subtract two year-month type variables and then multiple by 12 to get diff in months as follows:

```
12 * (as.yearmon(Date1) - as.yearmon(Date2))
```

Comment: Code only answers are normally discouraged.  Could you add an explanation as to why this works or why it is better than the other solutions?

Comment: @Jason Just did!

Comment: This works, but `as.yearmon()` is part of the `zoo` package and is not part of R base. If you have zoo installed: `12 * (zoo::as.yearmon(Date1) - zoo::as.yearmon(Date2))`

Answer (score 0):

Date difference in months

```
$date1 = '2017-01-20';
$date2 = '2019-01-20';

$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

echo $joining_months = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short and convenient way is this:

```
day1 <- as.Date('1991/04/12')
day2 <- as.Date('2019/06/10')
round(as.numeric(day2 - day1)/30.42)
```

[1] 338