# R - Extract date from string

Tags: r, date, extract, datediff

I'm using R and I have the following variables:

```
data$date1 (which is a date)
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01"
```

and

```
data$date2  (which is a numeric)
[1] 201602
```

I need to do a date difference but I don't know how to do it. I need to calculate the months difference.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Try `as.Date`, answers here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242955 and the `months` function

Comment: The answer to the title of your question is `as.Date(paste0(data$date2,"01"), format="%Y%m%d")`. This question has the rest [Number of months between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to transform the data$date2 into a date value