# Using ifelse statement in a sapply function

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, apply

I am trying to make a new column in my data.table. I have two columns, one with a start date and one with an end date. The starting date always is 2016-02-28. The end date in some cases is 2014-12-31 and in others it is 2020-12-31 (all in YYYY-MM-DD format).

In the first case it's evident that I should get a negative difference in dates. In the second case it is positive.

I want to use the sapply function with an ifelse statement to determine the difference in dates. Any time, the difference is negative, I want R to replace this with the value `1`.

I do this as follows.

```
sapply(df$end.date, function(x) { ifelse(df$end.date>start_date, as.integer(length(seq(from=start_date, to=as.POSIXct(x,format="%Y-%m-%d"), by ='month')) ), 1) } )
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error

```
Error in seq.POSIXt(from = start_date, to = as.POSIXct(df$end.date,  : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

How can I make this work?

PS: both start_date and df$end.date are in POSIXct format in a data.table.

Comment: You don’t use your `x` argument in the function.

Comment: No, The function you pass to `sapply` has an argument `x` that isn’t used in the function. Instead you use `df` (or nothing at all for `start_date`).

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you pass dates in `seq`function which need numeric values.

Comment: And yes guys the x is used in @Starwhat 's function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` is *already* vectorised, doubling up `sapply` and `ifelse` is redundant.

Unfortunately `ifelse` won’t work here because we  cannot get the month difference for negative dates (as per your comment). So we just use `if` in combination with `mapply` instead:

```
months_between = function (start, end) {
     if (end > start)
         length(seq(start, end, by = 'month'))
     else
         1
}

df$new_column = mapply(months_between, df$start.date, df$end.date)
```

I’m also pretty sure that there’s a better way to write `months_between` but I’m not versed in the base R date manipulation functions since they are generally quite bad; I recommend using the ‹lubridate› package instead.

Comment: Still get this error though

Error in seq.int(r1$mon, 12 * (to0$year - r1$year) + to0$mon, by) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: @Strawhat Ah, very good point, it will still fail for negative months. Guh. See my edit.

Comment: It works, though it takes a lot of time to run the mapply function. I'll wait for other responses and after that I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approach is overly complicated.  If you're going to use `sapply`, you ought to be able to avoid `ifelse` since you will be able to focus on one value at a time (this assumes you are running a vector through `sapply`. This might not hold true if running a list through `sapply`).  If you really want to use an `apply` function, however, you'd be better off using `mapply` with an `if ... else` clause.

But the `apply` function isn't necessary at all.  In fact, the `ifelse` function isn't necessary.  You can simplify the process a great deal with:

```
# Borrowed code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates/1996404
elapsed_months <- function(end_date, start_date) {
  mapply(
    function(end_date, start_date){
      ed <- as.POSIXlt(end_date)
      sd <- as.POSIXlt(start_date)
      12 * (ed$year - sd$year) + (ed$mon - sd$mon)
    },
    end_date,
    start_date,
    SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )
}


DFrame <- data.frame(start = rep(as.Date("2016-02-28"), 2),
                     end = as.Date(c("2014-12-31", "2020-12-31")))

DFrame$diff <- elapsed_months(DFrame$end, DFrame$start)
DFrame$diff[DFrame$diff < 0] <- 1

DFrame
```

All I did was calculate the difference for all of the variables, obtain an index for the negative values, and replace them with 1.

An alternative approach would be to do the indexing up front. This way you aren't calculating the difference in dates for any values you will eventually change.  This might have a benefit if you have a few million rows, but I would guess the performance increase would be small.

```
DFrame$diff2 <- vector("numeric", nrow(DFrame))
end_first <- DFrame$end < DFrame$start
DFrame$diff2[!end_first] <- elapsed_months(DFrame$end[!end_first], DFrame$start[!end_first]) 
DFrame$diff2[end_first] <- 1
```

Comment: Does `-` do the month-wise difference between dates?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I'll be honest, I didn't read too much into his code until I saw your answer. I just saw `sapply` and `ifelse` and knew there would be a better solution.  The text of his answer just said difference in dates.  I'll adapt my answer to get the desired output.

Comment: I borrowed code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates/1996404 to get the difference in months in a decent base solution.  There's probably a decent `lubridate` solution somewhere, but I haven't spent any time looking for it. @KonradRudolph