# Calculate difference between timestamps

Tags: r

I try to find the difference between two timestamps.

The codeQ:

```
survey <- data.frame(date=c("07/2012","07/2012"),tx_start=c("01/2012","01/2012"))
survey$date_diff <- as.Date(as.character(survey$date), format="%m/%Y")-
    as.Date(as.character(survey$tx_start), format="%m/%Y")
survey
```

I expect to have in the new column the different but I take NA

The results:

```
> survey
     date tx_start date_diff
1 07/2012  01/2012   NA days
2 07/2012  01/2012   NA days
```

What should I change to replace as.Date for months or years?

Update based on comment of Gregor:

```
    > survey <- data.frame(date=c("07/2012","07/2012"),tx_start=c("01/2012","01/2012"))
> survey$date <- as.Date(paste0("01/", as.character(survey$date)), "%d/%m/%Y")
> survey$tx_start <- as.Date(paste0("01/", as.character(survey$tx_start)), "%d/%m/%Y")
> survey$date_diff <- as.Date(survey$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")-
+     as.Date(survey$tx_start, format="%d/%m/%Y")
> survey
        date   tx_start date_diff
1 2012-07-01 2012-01-01  182 days
2 2012-07-01 2012-01-01  182 days
```

Comment: Your dates are missing the day, try `as.Date(paste0("01/", as.character(survey$date)), "%d/%m/%Y")` and the same for `tx_start`.

Comment: Ok, but since it is not, paste the day, it won't hurt, you will not change the original data.

Comment: @PitterJe, Rui is correct. You cannot have a date difference without the date. So paste in an arbitrary but consistent date to get the date difference.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank. I tried and edited the question but again the problem exist.

Comment: Since neither `date` nor `tx_start` has days, you will need to use the `paste` trick with both (and consistent date formats). However, once something has been cast with `as.Date`, you don't need to `as.Date(as.character())` it anymore - you've already done it!

Comment: @Gregor thank you I update the code based on your instructions and it works

Comment: As Nate said, check out the answers [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1995933/903061). There's a lot of good stuff there, especially Dirk's and pbnelson's answers.

Answer (score 1):

I usually convert my dates to POSIXct format.  Then, when direct differences are taken with normal syntax, you get an answer in units of seconds.  There is a `difftime()` function in base R that you can use as well:

```
survey <- data.frame(date=c("07/2012","07/2012"),tx_start=c("01/2012","01/2012"))

# Dates are finicky, add a day so that conversion will work
survey$date2 <- paste0("01/",survey$date)
survey$tx_start2 <- paste0("01/",survey$tx_start)

# conversion
survey$date2 <-  as.POSIXct(x=survey$date2,format="%d/%m/%Y")
survey$tx_start2 <-  as.POSIXct(x=survey$tx_start2,format="%d/%m/%Y")

# take the difference
survey$date_diff <- with(survey,difftime(time1=date2,time2=tx_start2,units="hours"))
```

Comment: There isn't, apparently, but you aren't the first to ask.  [Here's one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995984/8469286).  There may be something better out there, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @PitterJe look at the package called "lubridate" for difference in months