# Create Tenure column in R

Tags: r

I need to create a new column in current data frame from my original whose format given below.

```
Reg         Canceled
20161107    20171102
20120607    20131216 
20110105    20130524
```

The new column will be titled `Tenure`, and it should hold the difference in months between the date in the `Canceled` column and the one in the `Reg` column.

```
Reg          Canceled      Tenure
20161107    20171102         12
20120607    20130607         12
20110105    20110505          4
```

Comment: Are your "dates" stored as integers, characters or factors? And I assume you are just trying to calculate the number of months between Reg and Canceled where those values are in some sort of YYYYMMDD format?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, the dates are stored as integers and I am trying to calculate the number of months between Reg and Canceled where those values are formatted as YYYYMMDD. Essentially, I am adding a new column named tenure.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from
[Number of months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates/1996404)

```
df <- read.table(text='
Reg          Canceled      Tenure
20161107    20171102         12
                 20120607    20130607         12
                 20110105    20110505          4', header = T)
df$Tenure 

elapsed_months <- function(end_date, start_date) {
  ed <- as.POSIXlt(end_date)
  sd <- as.POSIXlt(start_date)
  12 * (ed$year - sd$year) + (ed$mon - sd$mon)
} 

df$Tenure2 <- elapsed_months(strptime(df$Canceled,'%Y%m%d'),strptime(df$Reg,'%Y%m%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
Reg <- c(       
"20161107",    
"20120607",    
"20110105"  
)
Canceled <- c(
  "20171102",
  "20131216" ,
  "20130524"
)
df <- data.frame(Reg=Reg, Canceled=Canceled)
parsed_reg <- gsub("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})", "\\1-\\2-\\3", df$Reg)
split_reg <- strsplit(parsed_reg, "-")
dates_reg <- t(data.frame(split_reg))
dates_reg <- data.frame(apply(dates_reg, 2, as.integer))
parsed_can <- gsub("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})", "\\1-\\2-\\3", df$Canceled)
split_can <- strsplit(parsed_can, "-")
dates_can <- t(data.frame(split_can))
dates_can <- data.frame(apply(dates_can, 2, as.integer))
colnames(dates_reg) <- c("year", "month", "day")
colnames(dates_can) <- c("year", "month", "day")

df$tenure <- (dates_can$year-dates_reg$year)*12 + (dates_can$month-dates_reg$month)
```