# Counting continuous sequences of months

Tags: r

If I have a vector of year and month coded like this:

```
ym <- c(
  201401,
  201403:201412,
  201501:201502,
  201505:201510,
  201403
)
```

And I'd like to end up with a vector that looks like this:

```
 [1]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  1  2  3  4  5  6  1
```

That is, I want to count continuous sequences of month records. Can anyone recommend an approach? I've spinning my wheels with something like this:

```
ym_date <- as.Date(paste0(ym, 01), format = "%Y%m%d")

diff(ym_date)
```

but haven't been able to get any farther because I'm not sure how to flag that start of a sequence when we are dealing with months. Any base R, tidyverse, data.frame centric or not solution would be welcomed.

Comment: Maybe of some help: [How to partition a vector into groups of regular, consecutive sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/how-to-partition-a-vector-into-groups-of-regular-consecutive-sequences)

Comment: Or [Number of months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: I might have poorly asked my question but I don't quite see how that one answers this question.

Comment: @akrun it isn't clear to me why my question was closed. The answer sort of answer the original post with something like this `tibble(ym, group = cumsum(c(1, diff(ym) != 1))) %>%  group_by(group) %>%  mutate(months = length(group))` but I don't consider it is trivial leap.

Comment: Your expected output based on the input `201501 201502 201505 201506` is `1 2 3 4` is that right

Comment: Not right - good catch

Comment: `as.numeric(substr(ym, 5, 6))`? It's sort of unclear what's being asked.

Comment: Have you changed the input again?

Comment: I did - sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry, the logic iis not clear to me

Comment: Maybe you can check my code and output

Comment: Yes and that was terrible SO manners by me. I can't say which one is objectively better.

Comment: @boshek It's ok.  Just that I was going in a different route with the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following base R code with `rle`

```
r <- unlist(sapply(rle(cumsum(c(1,round(as.numeric(diff(ym_date))/30.24)!=1)))$lengths,seq_along))
```

or with `ave`

```
r <- ave(ym,cumsum(c(1,round(as.numeric(diff(ym_date))/30.24)!=1)),FUN = seq_along)
```

such that

```
> r
 [1]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  1  2  3  4  5  6  1
```

Comment: Thank you. Question: can you explain why 30.24? It works but I'm not totally sure why.

Comment: @boshek this is used to calculate convert days to month, you can take it as a constant for this kind of calculation

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
mth <- month(ym_date)
new <- mth + cumsum(c(0, (mth %/% 12)[-length(mth)])) * 12
ave(mth, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(new) != 1)), FUN = seq_along)
#[1]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  1
```

It can be also written in a more compact way

```
ave(mth, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(c(0, head(cumsum(mth == 12), -1)) * 12 + mth) != 1)), FUN = seq_along)
#[1]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  1
```

Comment: Oops - I screwed up my expected output. I need the count to span the end of the year and into the next. So the output _should_ be `1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  1`