# In R: creating a variable that shows the difference in months between two date variables

Tags: r, date

I have looked around for ages trying to find what I am looking for but none of the code has given me what I want. I need to create a variable that calculates the difference in months between two date variables.

For example, if I have the data below:

```
start_date   end_date
2010-01-01  2010-12-31
2016-05-01  2016-12-31
2004-03-01  2004-10-31
1997-10-01  1998-08-31
```

I would like the outcome to look like the following:

```
start_date   end_date    month_count
2010-01-01  2010-12-31       12
2016-05-01  2016-12-31       8
2004-03-01  2004-10-31       8
1997-10-01  1998-08-31       11
```

Meaning I would like the whole last month to be included. Many of the codes I have checked have given me 11 months for the first observation instead of 12 for example. Also, many codes have said to specify the actual date but as I have a large dataset I can't do that, and would need to go by the variables instead.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You get 11 month in return, because from 2010-01-01 00:00:00 to 2010-12-31 00:00:00 is not 12 months, but 11 + 30/31 month. Just add one day to the end_date, en perform your operation again.

Comment: if all the dates have the 1 to 30 or 31 day gap you could do it by just adding 1 to the month. even something as simple as `month_count<-(lubridate::month(end_date)-lubridate::month(start_date))+1` would work

Comment: How can a project end before it started (row 2)? Given your comments below shouldn't the output for row 3 also count for years in between? Please clarify!

Comment: so sorry @AnilGoyal I had been mistaken when writing the question, I have now done the necessary edits/changes above for it to be correct

Comment: how do I use the year to account for this as you mentioned below?

Comment: Use `floor_date` and `ceiling_date` in that case from lubridate

Comment: could you give me an example? I am quite new to R and haven't really gotten the hang of it yet, thanks :)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates) for reference

Answer (score 1):

dplyr way

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~as.Date(.))) %>%
  mutate(months = (year(end_date) - year(start_date) * 12) + month(end_date) - month(start_date) + 1)
```

Comment: thanks for this, however if my start date is 1997-10-01 and end date is 1998-08-31, I get -1 instead of 10

Comment: In that case, your required output for riws 2&3 in sample given should also include years!! Please recheck

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way:

```
library(data.table)

dtt <- fread(text = 'start_date   end_date
2010-01-01  2010-12-31
2016-05-01  2010-12-31
2004-03-01  2010-10-31')

dtt[, month_count := month(end_date) - month(start_date) + 1]
dtt
#    start_date   end_date month_count
# 1: 2010-01-01 2010-12-31          12
# 2: 2016-05-01 2010-12-31           8
# 3: 2004-03-01 2010-10-31           8
```

Comment: now 2010-01-01 untill 2010-01-02 returns 1 month, while it is just one day...

Comment: @Wimpel, it seems that the OP "would like the whole last month to be included."