# Extract data based on time to death

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I'm analysing the pattern of spending for individuals before they died. My dataset contains individuals' monthly spending and their dates of death. The dataset looks similar to this:

```
ID 2018_11 2018_12 2019_01  2019_02 2019_03 2019_04 2019_05 2019_06 2019_07 2019_08 2019_09 2019_10 2019_11 2019_12 2020_01  date_of_death
 A     15      14       6      23      23       5       6      30       1       15      6       7       8      30       1      2020-01-02     
 B      2       5       6       7       7       8       9      15      12       14     31      30      31       0       0      2019-11-15
```

Each column denotes the month of the year. For example, "2018_11" means November 2018. The number in each cell denotes the spending in that specific month.

I would like to construct a data frame which contains the spending data of each individual in their last 0-12 months. It will look like this:

```
ID  last_12_month  last_11_month ...... last_1_month  last_0_month  date_of_death
 A        6             23                  30             1          2020-01-02
 B        2              5                  30            31          2019-11-15
```

Each individual died at different time. For example, individual A died on 2020-01-02, so the data of the "last_0_month" for this person should be extracted from the column "2020_01", and that of "last_12_month" extracted from "2019_01"; individual B died on 2019-11-15, so the data of "last_0_month" for this person should be extracted from the column "2019_11", and that of "last_12_month" should be extracted from the column "2018_11".

I will be really grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can find a similar approach to the one presented by @RuiBarradas but using `lubridate` for extracting the difference in months:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

# Initial data
df <- structure(list(
  ID = c("A", "B"),
  `2018_11` = c(15, 2),
  `2018_12` = c(14, 5),
  `2019_01` = c(6, 6),
  `2019_02` = c(23, 7),
  `2019_03` = c(23, 7),
  `2019_04` = c(5, 8),
  `2019_05` = c(6, 9),
  `2019_06` = c(30, 15),
  `2019_07` = c(1, 12),
  `2019_08` = c(15, 14),
  `2019_09` = c(6, 31),
  `2019_10` = c(7, 30),
  `2019_11` = c(8, 31),
  `2019_12` = c(30, 0),
  `2020_01` = c(1, 0),
  date_of_death = c("2020-01-02", "2019-11-15")
),
row.names = c(NA, -2L),
class = "data.frame"
)

# Convert to longer all cols that start with 20 (e.g. 2020, 2021)
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("20"), names_to = "month")

# treatment
df_long <- df_long %>%
  mutate(
    # To date, just in case
    date_of_death = as.Date(date_of_death),
    # Need to reformat the colnames from (e.g.) 2021_01 to 2021-01-01
    month_fmt = as.Date(paste0(gsub("_", "-", df_long$month), "-01")),
    # End of month
    month_fmt = ceiling_date(month_fmt, "month") - days(1),
    # End of month for month of death
    date_of_death_eom = ceiling_date(date_of_death, "month") - days(1),
    # Difference in months (using end of months
    month_diff = round(time_length(
        interval(month_fmt, date_of_death_eom),"month"),0)) %>%
  # Select only months bw 0 and 12
  filter(month_diff %in% 0:12) %>%
  # Create labels for the next step
  mutate(labs = paste0("last_", month_diff,"_month"))


# To wider
end <- df_long %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(ID, date_of_death),
    names_from = labs,
    values_from = value
  )

end
#> # A tibble: 2 x 15
#>   ID    date_of_death last_12_month last_11_month last_10_month last_9_month
#>   <chr> <date>                <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 A     2020-01-02                6            23            23            5
#> 2 B     2019-11-15                2             5             6            7
#> # ... with 9 more variables: last_8_month <dbl>, last_7_month <dbl>,
#> #   last_6_month <dbl>, last_5_month <dbl>, last_4_month <dbl>,
#> #   last_3_month <dbl>, last_2_month <dbl>, last_1_month <dbl>,
#> #   last_0_month <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! This is really clear!!

Answer (score 1):

**Using data.table and lubridate packages**

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(dt)

dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = c("ID", "date_of_death"))
dt[, since_death := interval(ym(variable), ymd(date_of_death)) %/% months(1)]
dt <- dcast(dt[since_death %between% c(0, 12)], ID + date_of_death ~ since_death, value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = sum)
setcolorder(dt, c("ID", "date_of_death", rev(names(dt)[3:15])))
setnames(dt, old = names(dt)[3:15], new = paste("last", names(dt)[3:15], "month", sep = "_"))
```

**Results**

```
dt
#    ID date_of_death last_12_month last_11_month last_10_month last_9_month last_8_month last_7_month last_6_month last_5_month last_4_month last_3_month
# 1:  A    2020-01-02             6            23            23            5            6           30            1           15            6            7
# 2:  B    2019-11-15             2             5             6            7            7            8            9           15           12           14
#    last_2_month last_1_month last_0_month
# 1:            8           30            1
# 2:           31           30           31
```

**Data**

```
dt <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B"), `2018_11` = c(15L, 2L), `2018_12` = c(14L, 
5L), `2019_01` = c(6L, 6L), `2019_02` = c(23L, 7L), `2019_03` = c(23L, 
7L), `2019_04` = c(5L, 8L), `2019_05` = c(6L, 9L), `2019_06` = c(30L, 
15L), `2019_07` = c(1L, 12L), `2019_08` = 15:14, `2019_09` = c(6L, 
31L), `2019_10` = c(7L, 30L), `2019_11` = c(8L, 31L), `2019_12` = c(30L, 
0L), `2020_01` = 1:0, date_of_death = structure(c(18263L, 18215L
), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

Reshape the data to long format, coerce the date columns to class `"Date"`, use [Dirk Eddelbuettel's accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates) to compute the date differences in months and keep the rows with month differences between 0 and 12.

This grouped long format is probably more useful and I compute means by group and plot the spending of the last 12 months prior to death but since the question asks for a wide format, the output data set `spending12_wide` is created.

```r
options(width=205)
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID 2018_11 2018_12 2019_01  2019_02 2019_03 2019_04 2019_05 2019_06 2019_07 2019_08 2019_09 2019_10 2019_11 2019_12 2020_01  date_of_death
 A     15      14       6      23      23       5       6      30       1       15      6       7       8      30       1      2020-01-02     
 B      2       5       6       7       7       8       9      15      12       14     31      30      31       0       0      2019-11-15 
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)


suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Dirk's functions
monnb <- function(d) { 
  lt <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(d, origin = "1900-01-01"))
  lt$year*12 + lt$mon 
} 
# compute a month difference as a difference between two monnb's
diffmon <- function(d1, d2) { monnb(d2) - monnb(d1) }

spending12 <- df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('20'), names_to = "month") %>% 
  mutate(month = as.Date(paste0(month, "_01"), "%Y_%m_%d"),
         date_of_death = as.Date(date_of_death)) %>%
  group_by(ID, date_of_death) %>%
  mutate(diffm = diffmon(month, date_of_death)) %>%
  filter(diffm >= 0 & diffm <= 12)

spending12 %>% summarise(spending = mean(value), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   ID    date_of_death spending
#>   <chr> <date>           <dbl>
#> 1 A     2020-01-02        12.4
#> 2 B     2019-11-15        13.6

spending12_wide <- spending12 %>%
  mutate(month = zoo::as.yearmon(month)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(ID, date_of_death),
    names_from = diffm,
    names_glue = "last_{.name}_month",
    values_from = value
  )

spending12_wide
#> # A tibble: 2 x 15
#> # Groups:   ID, date_of_death [2]
#>   ID    date_of_death last_12_month last_11_month last_10_month last_9_month last_8_month last_7_month last_6_month last_5_month last_4_month last_3_month last_2_month last_1_month last_0_month
#>   <chr> <date>                <int>         <int>         <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
#> 1 A     2020-01-02                6            23            23            5            6           30            1           15            6            7            8           30            1
#> 2 B     2019-11-15                2             5             6            7            7            8            9           15           12           14           31           30           31


ggplot(spending12, aes(month, value, color = ID)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>