# Number of months between two dates in r

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am new to R and not familiar with it.
I have the following data:

```
     Start.Date       
 1: 2020-09-15 
 2: 2021-08-10 
 3: 2015-08-25 
 4: 2021-10-11 
 5: 2021-08-15 
 6: 2018-06-05 
 7: 2021-06-10 
 8: 2020-05-13 
 9: 2021-08-03 
10: 2017-12-25
```

I want to have the duration between the current date and the start date in months?

I tried  the following but it didn't work:

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library("lubridate") 
currentDate <- Sys.Date()
StartDate <- as.Date(Mall_Data$Start.Date, format =  "%m/%d/%Y")
theduration<- interval(currentDate, StartDate) %% months(1)
```

Comment: Your start date format is Year-Month-Day, therefor: `as.Date(Mall_Data$Start.Date, format =  "%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 5):

you just have some typos and wrong formats in your code.
Your date format is false and `%%` will not work, but `%/%` will do the job.
Correct its here:

```
library(lubridate)

### worked with
Start.Date <- c("2020-09-15","2021-08-10","2015-08-25","2021-10-11","2021-08-15","2018-06-05","2021-06-10","2020-05-13","2021-08-03","2017-12-25")

### your corrected code
currentDate <- Sys.Date()
StartDate <- as.Date(Start.Date, format =  "%Y-%m-%d")
theduration <- interval(currentDate, StartDate) %/% months(1)
theduration
```

output is:

```
[1] -18  -7 -78  -5  -7 -45  -9 -22  -7 -50
```

I'll also refer to [Number of months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates)