# Calculate number of months between two dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have the following dates "7/06/2023" (column name "start") and "7/06/2024" (column name "end) and I would like to write a lines of code that calculate the number of months between my two dates, i.e. in this example 12 months.

I found the following question which is what I'm after but my dates are formatted differently so when I try

data[, months := (interval((start), (end)) %/% months(1))]

I get "all formats failed to parse, no formats found"

[Number of months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates)

Does anyone have a quick couple of lines of code I could use to calculate the number of months please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your dates are ambiguous, you need to convert them to dates first e.g. `as.Date(start, "%d/%m/%Y")`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
start_date <- as.Date("7/06/2023", format = "%m/%d/%Y") 
end_date <-  as.Date("7/06/2024" , format = "%m/%d/%Y") 
interval(start_date, end_date) %/% months(1)
```